# WordPress Child Theme: How to override parent theme .css files that exist in subdirectories?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I have a /lib/extends_script/extends-style.min.css file in my child theme that I'm trying to have override the version in the parent theme. I have the following code in place, but it still seems to be loading the parent version of the .css file. What am I doing wrong?

```
Child theme: functions.php

function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {

    // enqueue parent styles
    wp_enqueue_style('maple', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

    // enqueue child styles
    wp_enqueue_style('maple-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array('maple'), 99999);       
    wp_enqueue_style('tn-extends-lib-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/lib/extends_script/extends-style.min.css');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 20 );
```

The parent theme functions.php is enqueueing it in the following way:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'tn_register_frontend_script' ) ) {
    function tn_register_frontend_script() {
        // load css code
        wp_enqueue_style( 'tn-extends-lib-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/extends_script/extends-style.min.css', array(), TN_THEME_VERSION, 'all' );
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy file that including scripts or style from parent-theme to child-theme,
with the same nesting levels of folders, for example:

```
parent-theme/inc/theme_styles.php
```

to

```
child-theme/inc/theme_styles.php
```

and inside the same file but in child-theme replace

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

to

```
get_theme_file_uri()
```

and now wordpress check style path in child-theme first.

The stylesheet's file with the same path as in your parent-theme must be inside of your child-theme too